# Java compile error cannot find symbol method next()

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

When I run my program I got compilation error like this:

```
com/mycompany/sistemcatatpoinkeaktifan/KemahasiswaanController.java:[65,20] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method next()
  location: variable rs of type javax.xml.transform.Result
com/mycompany/sistemcatatpoinkeaktifan/KemahasiswaanController.java:[66,51] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getInt(java.lang.String)
  location: variable rs of type javax.xml.transform.Result
com/mycompany/sistemcatatpoinkeaktifan/KemahasiswaanController.java:[66,71] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getString(java.lang.String)
  location: variable rs of type javax.xml.transform.Result
com/mycompany/sistemcatatpoinkeaktifan/KemahasiswaanController.java:[66,102] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getInt(java.lang.String)
  location: variable rs of type javax.xml.transform.Result
4 errors
```

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.sistemcatatpoinkeaktifan;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;


public class KemahasiswaanController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private TextField inputKegiatan;
    @FXML 
    private Button buttonCreate;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonUpdate;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonDelete;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Menu> tvMenu;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Menu, Integer> colnomor;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Menu, String> coljenisKegiatan;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Menu, Integer> colpoin;
    
    public Connection getConnection(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:\\Documents\\Sem 5\\RPL\\punya maria\\SistemCatatPoinKeaktifanMaria\\db\\database.db");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
    public ObservableList<Menu> getMenuList(){
        ObservableList<Menu> menuList = FXCollection.observableArrayList();
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT JenisKegiatan, Poin FROM KemahasiswaanNatasha";
        Statement st;
        Result rs;
        ObservableList<Menu> MenuList = null;
        try{
           st = conn.createStatement();
           rs = (Result) st.executeQuery(query);
           Menu KegiatanKemahasiswaan;
           while(rs.next()){
               KegiatanKemahasiswaan = new Menu(rs.getInt("nomor"), rs.getString("jenisKegiatan"), rs.getInt("poin"));
               MenuList.add(KegiatanKemahasiswaan);
           }
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        return MenuList;
    }
    public void ShowMenu(){
        ObservableList<Menu> list = getMenuList();
        colnomor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Menu, Integer>("nomor"));
        coljenisKegiatan.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Menu, String>("Kegiatan"));
        colpoin.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Menu, Integer>("Poin"));
        tvMenu.setItems(list);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ShowMenu();
    }    

    private static class FXCollection {

        private static ObservableList<Menu> observableArrayList() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        public FXCollection() {
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: cannot find symbol symbol: method next() location: variable rs of type javax.xml.transform.Result => this means that the class Result doesn't have a next() method, yet you try to call it somewhere. Most likely, you meant ResultSet or something similar

Comment: Indeed, you're incorrectly casting the result of executeQuery to `Result`, this should be `java.sql.ResultSet`

Comment: a) basically unrelated to javafx - debugging involves isolating a problem as much as possible b) java naming conventions c) please format the stacktrace as code - it's unreadable as-is :)

Comment: hey .. why did you revert the formatting? Somebody did _your_ job for you and you destroyed it again? *unbelievable

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have declared `rs` to be of the type `javax.xml.transform.Result` instead of `java.sql.ResultSet`, and the methods you're trying to call (like `next()`, `getInt(String)` and `getString(String)` do not exist in `javax.xml.transform.Result`.

The line

```java
Result rs;
```

should be

```
ResultSet rs;
```

and

```
rs = (Result) st.executeQuery(query);
```

should be

```
rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

In addition, your code could be further improved by learning about [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), as you're currently leaking the connection, statement and result set.